# Optimising timers for modern browsers (Chrome) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, timer, cross-browser

I have written a web application which relies heavily on timers running in background tabs. With the more recent Chrome browsers (>Chrome 57), the default option is for "expensive" timers to be throttled if they're in the background - I understand that this feature can be disabled in `chrome://flags/`, but I want to avoid asking users to do this. An example of the timer is, which uses JQuery/JS and refreshes every second:

```js
function startTimer(seconds) {
  var timer = seconds - 1;
  var refresh = setInterval(function() { // refresh every second
    var output = displaySeconds(timer); // displaySeconds formats the time
    $("#timer").text(output);
    $("title").html(output + " - Timer");
    if (--timer < 0) {
      clearInterval(refresh); // exit refresh loop
    };
  }, 1000);
```

Often this timer is disrupted heavily by the browser and lasts about 50% longer than the `seconds` parameter given as input. I have also minified the JS, but understand that this only really reduces the size of the file so doesn't help.

What would be a sensible and browser agnostic way of optimising this to run smoothly in the background?

Ideas I have: - Find out when tab is in background using some relevant library, reduce the refresh rate to something more coarse (2 or 3 seconds) - seems complicated though!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a Chrome specific issue; timers are notoriously unreliable in JS, it's just that most of them are short enough that you don't notice. What exactly is the purpose of this logic? It may be worth looking for an alternative, if possible.

Comment: Why would increasing the refresh rate work? That's already what the browser does, so it doesn't seem like *you* changing it should affect anything. Unless your logic is tied to the update interval, in which case you might be better off just measuring what the time between ticks is each time and then use that for your calculations.

Comment: I want the timer (say 15 mins or 900 seconds) to be counting down and visible to the user in the browser tab. My thought is that breaking the 900 seconds down into 300 refreshes and only updating the tab every 3 seconds would be more efficient. Also note to the editor, I am British so will not be spelling optimise with a z :)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions (largely in-line with your own solutions):

- Make the timer dependent on the start-time. In that way, you won't be as dependent on the exact time that the timers fire:

(untested)

```js
function startTimer(seconds) {
    var endTime = new Date().valueOf() + seconds * 1000;
    var refresh = setInterval(function() { // refresh every second
    var now = new Date().valueOf(); // current time in ms
    var output = displaySeconds((endTime - now) / 1000); // displaySeconds formats the time
    $("#timer").text(output);
    $("title").html(output + " - Timer");
    if (now > endTime) {
      clearInterval(refresh); // exit refresh loop
    };
  }, 1000);
```

- Don't update the GUI if the tab is in the background. Look at the example on: 
  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

After applying that code, the GUI-updates could be wrapped in a `if (doVisualUpdates)`